# Gaps and Islands - get a list of dates unemployed over a date range with Postgresl

Tags: postgresql, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I have a table called Position, in this table, I have the following, dates are inclusive (yyyy-mm-dd), below is a simplified view of the employment dates

```
id, person_id, start_date, end_date  , title
1 , 1        , 2001-12-01, 2002-01-31, 'admin'
2 , 1        , 2002-02-11, 2002-03-31, 'admin'
3 , 1        , 2002-02-15, 2002-05-31, 'sales'
4 , 1        , 2002-06-15, 2002-12-31, 'ops'
```

I'd like to be able to calculate the gaps in employment, assuming some of the dates overlap to produce the following output for the person with id=1

```
person_id, start_date, end_date  , last_position_id, gap_in_days
1        , 2002-02-01, 2002-02-10, 1               , 10
1        , 2002-06-01, 2002-06-14, 3               , 14
```

I have looked at numerous solutions, UNIONS, Materialized views, tables with generated calendar date ranges, etc. I really am not sure what is the best way to do this. Is there a single query where I can get this done?

Comment: what you mean `assuming some of the dates overlap` ?

Comment: what is `last_position_id`?

Comment: a person can have 2 positions hence dates overlap

Comment: last_position_id is the id of the position before the gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first you need to find what dates overlaps [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)
- then merge those ranges as a single one and keep the last id
- finally calculate the ranges of days between one `end_date` and the next `start_date - 1`

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/76e20c/33)**

```
with find_overlap as (
  SELECT t1."id" as t1_id, t1."person_id", t1."start_date", t1."end_date",
         t2."id" as t2_id, t2."start_date" as t2_start_date, t2."end_date" as t2_end_date
  FROM Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
    ON t1."person_id" = t2."person_id"
   AND t1."start_date" <= t2."end_date"
   AND t1."end_date"   >= t2."start_date"
   AND t1.id < t2.id
), merge_overlap as (
  SELECT 
         person_id,
         start_date,
         COALESCE(t2_end_date, end_date) as  end_date,
         COALESCE(t2_id, t1_id) as last_position_id
  FROM find_overlap
  WHERE t1_id NOT IN (SELECT t2_id FROM find_overlap WHERE t2_ID IS NOT NULL)
), cte as (
  SELECT *, 
         LEAD(start_date) OVER (partition by person_id order by start_date) next_start
  FROM merge_overlap 
) 
SELECT *, 
       DATE_PART('day', 
                  (next_start::timestamp - INTERVAL '1 DAY') - end_date::timestamp
                ) as days 
FROM cte
WHERE next_start IS NOT NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| person_id | start_date |   end_date | last_position_id | next_start | days |
|-----------|------------|------------|------------------|------------|------|
|         1 | 2001-12-01 | 2002-01-31 |                1 | 2002-02-11 |   10 |
|         1 | 2002-02-11 | 2002-05-31 |                3 | 2002-06-15 |   14 |
```

Comment: This assume only simple overlap between 2 dates. If you have a three way overlap maybe need do a recursive query first

Comment: why I got the correct answer. Even when my asnwer is correct S-Man answer seem simpler

Answer (score 2):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7c8754b96864cd6db9c3f3eb266010e9)

You just need the `lead()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). With this you are able to get a value (`start_date` in this case) to the current row.

```
SELECT
    person_id,
    end_date + 1 AS start_date,
    lead - 1 AS end_date,
    id AS last_position_id,
    lead - (end_date + 1) AS gap_in_days
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        lead(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY start_date)
    FROM
        positions
) s
WHERE lead - (end_date + 1) > 0
```

After getting the next `start_date` you are able to compare it with the current `end_date`. If they differ, you have a gap. These positive values can be filtered within the `WHERE` clause.

(if 2 positions overlap, the diff is negative. So it can be ignored.)